# Google Sheets run script when cell has one of two defined text values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets run the "CopyImages" script when cell E252 has either "V" or "mV" selected.

The code below works for "mV", but cannot get the other choice of "V" to work.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'E252' || e.value !== 'mV') return;
  CopyImages();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'E252' || e.value !== 'V') return;
  CopyImages();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'E252' || e.value !== 'mV') return;
  CopyImages();
}
```

Comment: Welcome. When you're testing for the negative result (is not equal to), you don't need the second equals sign. Try: `!=`. For example, `if(e.range.getA1Notation() != 'E252' || e.value != 'V') return;`

Comment: Why you have 3 `onEdit` functions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the three onEdit's with this single one

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'E252' || ["mV", "V"].indexOf(e.value) === -1) return;
CopyImages()
}
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Most welcome @DaveRollins. If that helped, please accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers